# On the "Cash" problem set of CS-50 (2022) my program gets one coin less

Tags: cs50

I have tried to run the program and in my logic it seems to work correctly but it actually calculates ONE LESS coin when run.

If I put ¢26 cents y get a print of: 1 instead of 2.

With ¢68 I get: 6 instead of 7

**And if I try to put ¢25 I get: 6!**

I think that the initial CENTS value when prompted for some reason is **VALUE -1**. But I am not sure and cannot find any problem. Can anyone help?

**Code to ask for the cents owed:**

```
int get_cents(void)
 {
int cents;
do
{
    cents = get_int ("Cents?: ");
}
while (cents < 0);
return cents;
}
```

**Here is the code for calculating the quarters, dimes, nickels and pennies:**

```
int calculate_quarters(int cents)
{
int quarters = 0;
while (cents >= 25)
{
    cents = cents-25;
    quarters ++;
}
return quarters;
}

int calculate_dimes(int cents)
{
int dimes = 0;
while (cents >= 10)
{
    cents = cents -10;
    dimes ++;
}
return dimes;
 }

int calculate_nickels(int cents)
{
int nickels = 0;
while (cents >= 5)
{
    cents = cents -5;
    nickels++;
}
return nickels;
}

 int calculate_pennies(int cents)
{
int pennies = 0;
while (cents >= 1)
{
cents = cents -1;
pennies++;
}
return pennies;
```

}

**Here is the code that calculates the total sum of the coins:**

```
// Sum coins
int coins = quarters + dimes + nickels + pennies;

// Print total number of coins to give the customer
printf("%i\n", coins);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the code is correct but for some reason when I run it on a different C file is when it gets the error.

I usually work with two programs *"Cash.C"* and *"Cash2.c"* so that I can have two versions of it and try to change things.
IT IS THE SAME CODE ON "CASH.C" THAT IN "CASH2.C" and they get different results.

Why?

I did it on VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

your code is great, the only bug that you have is that you subtract the value of the coin before adding 1 to the number of that particular coin. For instance, this part of your code takes the value of cents entered by the user, subtracts 25 first then adds 1 to quarters, resulting in you having 25 less at the end, therefore one less quarter. The same goes for all the other coins.

```
int calculate_quarters(int cents)
{
int quarters = 0;
while (cents >= 25)
{
    cents = cents-25;
    quarters ++;
}
return quarters;
}
```

The solution is simple, just flip the process and make sure while the condition is true, add 1 to quarters first, then subtract 25 from cents. Like this:

```
int calculate_quarters(int cents)
{
int quarters = 0;
while (cents >= 25)
{
    quarters ++;
    cents = cents-25;  
}
return quarters;
}
```

make sure to also do this to the rest of the coins.